# Enforcing non-emptyness of scala varargs at compile time

Tags: scala

I have a function that expects a variable number of parameters of the same type, which sounds like the textbook use case for varargs:

```
def myFunc[A](as: A*) = ???
```

The problem I have is that `myFunc` cannot accept empty parameter lists. There's a trivial way of enforcing that at runtime:

```
def myFunc[A](as: A*) = {
  require(as.nonEmpty)
  ???
}
```

The problem with that is that it happens at *runtime*, as opposed to *compile time*. I would like the compiler to reject `myFunc()`.

One possible solution would be:

```
def myFunc[A](head: A, tail: A*) = ???
```

And this works when `myFunc` is called with inline arguments, but I'd like users of my library to be able to pass in a `List[A]`, which this syntax makes very awkward.

I could try to have both:

```
def myFunc[A](head: A, tail: A*) = myFunc(head +: tail)
def myFunc[A](as: A*) = ???
```

But we're right back where we started: there's now a way of calling `myFunc` with an empty parameter list.

I'm aware of scalaz's `NonEmptyList`, but in as much as possible, I'd like to stay with stlib types.

Is there a way to achieve what I have in mind with just the standard library, or do I need to accept some runtime error handling for something that really feels like the compiler should be able to deal with?

Comment: And if your user passes you an empty list? I really think the `def myFunc[A](head: A, tail: A*) = ...` is the way to go. Very simply conveys to the user the intent that you must give it at least one argument.

Comment: @badcook I agree that's standard, but it's also a nuisance if you want to pass the Seq to another function, since you have to rebuild it (prepend the head to tail). I wonder why this isn't a bigger deal. They could have a syntax `def f(x: X+)`. I think long ago, there was an idea for regex-like syntaxes.

Comment: @som-snytt that kind of syntax seems tough to do at compile time without some sort of `NonEmptyList` type that `_*` could key off of (unless you just drop `_*`). And you're going to likely need to do the same head, tail rebuild to get the `NonEmptyList` in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

What about something like this?

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def myFunc()(implicit ev: Nothing) = ???
def myFunc[A](as: A*) = println(as)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

myFunc: ()(implicit ev: Nothing)Nothing <and> [A](as: A*)Unit
myFunc: ()(implicit ev: Nothing)Nothing <and> [A](as: A*)Unit

scala> myFunc(3)
WrappedArray(3)

scala> myFunc(List(3): _*)
List(3)

scala> myFunc()
<console>:13: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: Nothing
       myFunc()
             ^

scala>
```

Replacing Nothing with a class that has an appropriate `implicitNotFound` annotation should allow for a sensible error message.

Comment: That's a good one. And make the ev class sealed to make sure.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov but still you can use it like this `myFunc(List(): _*)` .. which the OP doesn't like/want

Comment: @som-snytt but still you can use it like this myFunc(List(): _*) .. which the OP doesn't like/want

Comment: I wasn't sure if the goal was just to prevent `myFunc()` or to also prevent `myFunc(List(): _*)`.  I'm pretty sure a compile-time failure for that is not possible, because the varargs type is Seq[T], and I don't see how you can use the native varargs mechanism and enforce a non-empty Seq.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start out with what I think is your base requirement: the ability to define `myFunc` in some way such that the following occurs at the Scala console when a user provides literals. Then maybe if we can achieve that, we can try to go for varargs.

```
myFunc(List(1)) // no problem
myFunc(List[Int]()) // compile error!
```

Moreover, we don't want to have to force users either to split a list into a head and tail or have them convert to a `::`.

Well when we're given literals, since we have access to the syntax used to construct the value, we can use macros to verify that a list is non-empty. Moreover, there's already a library that'll do it for us, namely [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined)!

```
scala> refineMV[NonEmpty]("Hello")
res2: String Refined NonEmpty = Hello

scala> refineMV[NonEmpty]("")
<console>:39: error: Predicate isEmpty() did not fail.
            refineMV[NonEmpty]("")
                              ^
```

Unfortunately this is still problematic in your case, because you'll need to put `refineMV` into the body of your function at which point the literal syntactically disappears and macro magic fails.

Okay what about the general case that doesn't rely on syntax?

```
// Can we do this?
val xs = getListOfIntsFromStdin() // Pretend this function exists
myFunc(xs) // compile error if xs is empty
```

Well now we're up against a wall; there's no way a compile time error can happen here since the code has already been compiled and yet clearly `xs` could be empty. We'll have to deal with this case at runtime, either in a type-safe manner with `Option` and the like or with something like runtime exceptions. But maybe we can do a little better than just throw our hands up in the air. There's two possible paths of improvement.

1. Somehow provide `implicit` evidence that `xs` is nonempty. If the compiler can find that evidence, then great! If not, it's on the user to provide it somehow at runtime.
2. Track the provenance of `xs` through your program and statically prove that it must be non-empty. If this cannot be proved, either error out at compile time or somehow force the user to handle the empty case.

Once again, unfortunately this is problematic.

1. I strongly suspect this is not possible (but this is still only a suspicion and I would be happy to be proved wrong). The reason is that ultimately `implicit` resolution is type-directed which means that Scala gets the ability to do type-level computation on types, but Scala has no mechanism that I know of to do type-level computation on values (i.e. dependent typing). We require the latter here because `List(1, 2, 3)` and `List[Int]()` are indistinguishable at the type level.
2. Now you're in SMT solver land, which does have some efforts in other languages (hello [Liquid Haskell](http://goto.ucsd.edu/~rjhala/liquid/haskell/blog/blog/2013/01/31/safely-catching-a-list-by-its-tail.lhs/)!). Sadly I don't know of any such efforts in Scala (and I imagine it would be a harder task to do in Scala).

**The bottom line is that when it comes to error checking there is no free lunch**. A compiler can't magically make error handling go away (although it can tell you when you don't strictly need it), the best it can do is yell at you when you forget to handle certain classes of errors, which is itself very valuable. To underscore the no free lunch point, let's return to a language that does have dependent types (Idris) and see how it handles non-empty values of `List` and the prototypical function that breaks on empty lists, `List.head`.

First we get a compile error on empty lists

```
Idris> List.head []
(input):1:11:When checking argument ok to function Prelude.List.head:
        Can't find a value of type 
                NonEmpty []
```

Good, what about non-empty lists, even if they're obfuscated by a couple of leaps?

```
Idris> :let x = 5
-- Below is equivalent to 
-- val y = identity(Some(x).getOrElse(3))
Idris> :let y = maybe 3 id (Just x)
-- Idris makes a distinction between Natural numbers and Integers
-- Disregarding the Integer to Nat conversion, this is 
-- val z = Stream.continually(2).take(y)
Idris> :let z = Stream.take (fromIntegerNat y) (Stream.repeat 2)
Idris> List.head z
2 : Integer
```

It somehow works! What if we really don't let the Idris compiler know anything about the number we pass along and instead get one at runtime from the user? We blow up with a truly gargantuan error message that starts with `When checking argument ok to function Prelude.List.head: Can't find a value of type NonEmpty...`

```
import Data.String

generateN1s : Nat -> List Int
generateN1s x = Stream.take x (Stream.repeat 1)

parseOr0 : String -> Nat
parseOr0 str = case parseInteger str of
                    Nothing => 0
                    Just x => fromIntegerNat x

z : IO Int
z = do
  x <- getLine
  let someNum = parseOr0 x
  let firstElem = List.head $ generateN1s someNum -- Compile error here
  pure firstElem
```

Hmmm... well what's the type signature of `List.head`?

```
Idris> :t List.head
-- {auto ...} is roughly the same as Scala's implicit
head : (l : List a) -> {auto ok : NonEmpty l} -> a
```

Ah so we just need to provide a `NonEmpty`.

```
data NonEmpty : (xs : List a) -> Type where
    IsNonEmpty : NonEmpty (x :: xs)
```

Oh a `::`. And we're back at square one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `scala.collection.immutable.::`

`::` is the cons of the list

defined in std lib

```
::[A](head: A, tail: List[A])
```

use `::` to define `myFunc`

```
def myFunc[A](list: ::[A]): Int = 1

def myFunc[A](head: A, tail: A*): Int = myFunc(::(head, tail.toList))
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> def myFunc[A](list: ::[A]): Int = 1
myFunc: [A](list: scala.collection.immutable.::[A])Int

scala> def myFunc[A](head: A, tail: A*): Int = myFunc(::(head, tail.toList))
myFunc: [A](head: A, tail: A*)Int
```

Comment: Clever, but I feel it doesn't really address the issue: if I have a `List[A]` to pass to `myFunc`, I still need to cast it to a `::`, which is validated at runtime.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo Users has to send `::(1, List(2))` to the myFunc. We cannot take List as input because List can be empty .. thats why we take `cons` as input .

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo I don;t see any other way to do it. Its not possible to allow users to send List as input and enforce non emptiness of the list at compile time. Good thing is you need not use external libraries

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo this solution pushes the responsibility of making sure they're passing a non-empty list to your caller, which I feel is the correct place in this case. If you want to make their lives a little easier, you can give them a converter e.g. `def listToCons[A](list: List[A]): ::[A] = new ::(list.head, list.tail)` with an appropriate `@throws` warning in the Scaladoc. If you think they can handle it, you can even make it `implicit`.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo also, this way at least gives your caller a chance to statically guarantee that they're giving you a non-empty list.

Comment: I agree, it's not so burdensome to require `::(17, 42 :: Nil)` to get cons. Though really they'd need to NEL if this is a great feature.